# Is there a way to correlate ElasticSearch search hits with the queried terms (REST API, ES 7.10)

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

I'm writing a service that essentially censors blacklisted words (cursewords, etc) in a text. For this purpose I have an ElasticSearch index with all the blacklisted words processed with a stemming analyzer, so that if I have indexed "f__k" I can get hits for "f___er" etc.

I query ES via the REST API for the sentence that needs to be censored. At query time I use a tokenizing + stemming query-time analyzer; fuzziness is currently off, but I eventually also want to enable that, to catch cases of bad spelling or intentional obfuscation.

In order to do the censoring I need to be able to identify which hit correlates with which search term(s).

Is this possible to do with the REST API on ElasticSearch 7.10+?

Thanks

Comment: why you didnt used stopwords token filter? you can easily list your f words in a file and use as stop word.

Comment: Interesting idea. Would stemming and fuzzy search work or the stop word matching  is done literally?

Answer (score -1):

Elasticsearch has a explain API that returns information about why a specific document matches (or doesn’t match) a query. for more information you can check Elasticsearch official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html).

Comment: It seems I'd need to run one _explain request for each hit document id, this might turn to be prohibitively expensive when a sentence triggers multiple hits. 

Also parsing the response seems non-trivial -  it seems the query that's explained is part of the free-form "description" field in the "details" array elements. Honestly, I think this particular API is more geared towards human consumption.